# Fortify 4.2: Translator execution failed. Status 139

Tags: fortify

When running the following command: **sourceanalyzer -debug -b $build_id touchless make**

I'm getting this error:

```
Compiling C++ myFile.C

[ERROR]: Translator execution failed. Please consult the Troubleshooting section of the User Manual.

Translator returned status 139:

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/atomicity.h”, line 51: warning identifier

            “__sync_fetch_and_add” is undefined

{ return __sync_fetch_and_add(__mem, __val); }

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/atomicity.h”, line 55: warning identifier

            “__sync_fetch_and_add” is undefined

{  __sync_fetch_and_add(__mem, __val); }

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/new”, line 95: warning: first parameter of allocation

                            Function must be of type “size_t”

            Void* operator new(std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc);

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/new”, line 96: warning: first parameter of allocation

                            Function must be of type “size_t”

            Void* operator new[](std::size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc);

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/new”, line 99: warning: first parameter of allocation

                            Function must be of type “size_t”

            Void* operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) throw ();

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/new”, line 100: warning: first parameter of allocation

                            Function must be of type “size_t”

            Void* operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) throw ();

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/new”, line 105: warning: first parameter of allocation

                            Function must be of type “size_t”

            Inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* __p) throw (){ return __p; }

“/usr/include/c++/4.3/new”, line 105: warning: first parameter of allocation

                            Function must be of type “size_t”

            Inline void* operator new[](std::size_t, void* __p) throw (){ return __p; }

“/opt/ilog51/views51/include/ilog/list.h”, line 77: warning: first parameter of allocation function must be of type “size_t”

IL_MLK_DECL();

“/opt/ilog51/views51/include/ilog/list.h”, line 110: warning:  no appropriate operator delete is visible

{ e(); delete_first; _first; _first = _last 0; _length = 0; }
```

Furthermore, when uploading the FPR file to SSC, under Artifacts the status is: Error Processing.  And when auditing issues, the ssc is unable to locate source files.

Any ideas about this issues ?

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that the older gcc 4.3 (year 2008?) used compiler built-ins that were specific to GCC, while Fortify relies on Clang to translate the source code.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html